# svcutil tool doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I went into that directory:

```
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin
```

and when I press the tool, it triggers and after half a second it disappears, preventing me from using it..

I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate

UPDATE:

it told me that there is an httpGet error downloading the path..when I used this command:

```
scvutil http://localhost:8080/MagicEightBallService /out:myProxy.cs /config:app.config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scvutil is a command line app that requires you to pass parameters.  It sounds form your description like you are launching it from Explorer by double clicking on it.  That won't work as you will just run the exe without any command line options passed in, and as a result it will just output the list of possible parameters.

To use it properly, launch it within a command prompt, and take notice of the parameters you need to supply, or read up on its usage [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)

Comment: Okay, so it is being used with an external command prompt..is there an option to launch a command prompt from visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

It's a command line tool. You need to supply some parameters:

[ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (Svcutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx)

Comment: How do I supply it with parameters without opening it

Comment: You don't.  You need to run it from the command prompt and supply the parameters there.

Comment: By Using the command line. You know with the keyboard, typing stuff in and all that old school stuff.